# CentOS 6.3. Update from mininstall to full edition

Tags: centos

I want to install CentOS on my laptop. And DVD .iso images requre 4+gb flash drive, but I have flash drive  only with 2gb. So it is possible to download only `mininstall` edition, and then upgrade it to "full" edition of CentOS 6.3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Once you get an installed instance, you should be able to `yum install` or `yum groupinstall` the packages or groups you want to use; as they should come directly from the yum mirrors on the internet.

This is more or less how I do standard installs -- I do a minimal install, then a `yum -y update`, then install the groups and packages I need.  Since the updated packages are coming from the internet anyways, there's little point in installing packages from local storage that are going to get immediately updated.